# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)

Tags: python

La idea del código es que itere por una lista de listas y me imprima los valores en 3 columnas pero me da error. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

```
 cadenas=[['manzanas', 'naranjas', 'cerezas', 'plátano'],['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
 ['perros', 'gatos', 'alces ', 'ganso']]
 for i,j,e in zip(cadenas):
     palabra1=i
     palabras2=j
     palabra3=e

     print(palabra1,palabras2,palabra3)
```

Answer (score 3):

La función `zip()` es utilizada para mapear los mismos índices en más de un iterable, creando un objeto zip. En otras palabras, empareja el primer elemento de cada iterador luego a los segundos elementos y así sucesivamente.
Si utilizas el operador `*` con `zip`, convierte los elementos de los iterables en elementos separados; es decir, descomprime el iterable dado. Al aplicarlo a una matriz, obtienes la transpuesta de la matriz.
Para tu problema quedaría así:

```
for i in zip(*cadenas):
    print(' '.join(i))
```

Mostrando en consola:

```
manzanas Alice perros
naranjas Bob gatos  
cerezas Carol alces 
plátano David ganso
```

La función `join()` se utiliza para devolver una cadena que contiene todos los elementos de la secuencia unidos por un separador str, en este caso un espacio en blanco.